# "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'refreshUI' of null" when use ej2 grid and refresh datasourse grid

Tags: angular, grid

I have function refesh grid

angular 8, @syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids

I have function refresh grid, sometimes run successfully, sometimes causes error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'refreshUI' of null

Code:

```
refreshGrid(dataSource: ShipModel[]) {
    this.dataSourceShips = dataSource;
    this.gridTau.refresh();
}
```

Comment: This happens because you are trying to read `refreshUI` of a null reference. Concerning the information you give (it is even probably irrelevant in this case), that is what I can tell. We need more details. This blog post would help you a lot with debugging: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/